# Drop and create affected tables when model changes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

What if you want to drop and create affected tables only? Say I have two `DbContext` classes connecting to the same database. I would like to drop and create only affected context tables.

None of the existing database initialization strategies could help.
I tried `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`, `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges`, `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`. So I need to deal with a `CustomDBInitializer`.

Comment: If they connect to the same database, why do you need 2 dbcontext ? Why not one ?

Comment: The migration patterns you listed don't target tables, but a database as a whole. The easiest solution is to generate an initial migration script with no entities, then add each context specific tables to that context and generate a new migration script. From there use the CreateDatabaseIfNotExists initializer to be sure that one context doesn't inadvertently delete the database (and tables) the other context was using.

Comment: @Zysce because I'm developing some plugins and wan't them to use a single database